AssertionError when using pyinsane2 to scan with HP OfficeJet Pro scanner over ESCL
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to scan documents using the pyinsane2 library in Python with an HP OfficeJet Pro scanner over ESCL (Ethernet Scanner Control Language). Despite initializing the scanner successfully, I encounter an AssertionError during the scanning process.
Steps Taken:
Initialized the pyinsane2 library successfully.
Retrieved a list of available scanner devices and selected the HP OfficeJet Pro scanner over ESCL.
Set scanner options such as resolution and color mode.
Initiated a scan session and attempted to read the scanned image data.
Encountered an AssertionError during the __get_imgs method of the abstract_proc.py file in the pyinsane2 library.

import pyinsane2

pyinsane2.init()
try:
    devices = pyinsane2.get_devices()
    assert(len(devices) > 0)
    device = devices[0]
    print("I'm going to use the following scanner: %s" % (str(device)))

    pyinsane2.set_scanner_opt(device, 'resolution', [300])

    pyinsane2.set_scanner_opt(device, 'mode', ['Color'])


    pyinsane2.maximize_scan_area(device)

    scan_session = device.scan(multiple=False)
    try:
        while True:
            scan_session.scan.read()
    except EOFError:
        pass
    image = scan_session.images[-1]
finally:
    pyinsane2.exit()


**Error Exception : **
/media/tareq/G/D/AsdWork/sane_python/pythonProject/.venv/bin/python /media/tareq/G/D/AsdWork/sane_python/pythonProject/main.py 
INFO   Pyinsane_daemon Ready
I'm going to use the following scanner: 'escl:http://192.168.1.119:8080' (ESCL, HP OfficeJet Pro 9010 series [36F9BE], flatbed scanner)
Capability : [(null)]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Capability : [image/jpeg]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/tareq/G/D/AsdWork/sane_python/pythonProject/main.py", line 20, in <module>
    scan_session = device.scan(multiple=False)
  File "/media/tareq/G/D/AsdWork/sane_python/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinsane2/sane/abstract_proc.py", line 268, in scan
    return ScanSession(self, multiple)
  File "/media/tareq/G/D/AsdWork/sane_python/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinsane2/sane/abstract_proc.py", line 208, in __init__
    self._remote_session = remote_do('scan', scanner.name, multiple)
  File "/media/tareq/G/D/AsdWork/sane_python/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinsane2/sane/abstract_proc.py", line 68, in remote_do
    length = struct.unpack("i", length)[0]
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/tareq/G/D/AsdWork/sane_python/pythonProject/main.py", line 28, in <module>
    pyinsane2.exit()
  File "/media/tareq/G/D/AsdWork/sane_python/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinsane2/sane/abstract_proc.py", line 130, in exit
    remote_do('exit')
  File "/media/tareq/G/D/AsdWork/sane_python/pythonProject/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyinsane2/sane/abstract_proc.py", line 64, in remote_do
    os.write(fifo_c2s, length)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Process finished with exit code 1


Attempts to Solve:
Verified scanner connection and configuration.
Checked network connection between computer and scanner.
Updated pyinsane2 library to the latest version.
Looked for additional error messages or logs.

Environment Details:
Python version: [3.8.10]
Operating System: [Ubuntu 20]
Scanner:  [HP OfficeJet Pro 9010 series] over ESCL

Expected Outcome:
I expected the scanning process to proceed without errors and to retrieve the scanned image data successfully.
